# Generate and place objects automatically via Python in Maya

Tags: python, 3d, maya

I need to know how to generate some objects using Python in Maya, and then place them separated by 15 along X axis automatically. I tried to write a code but it did not work.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

i = 0
while i < 10:
    cmds.polyCube()
    i = i + 1

objects = cmds.ls( type = "shape" )

for j in objects:
    cmds.setAttr( "%s.translateX" % item, 15 )
```

Help me to solve my problem, please.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put the list return by maya command into variables.

```
for i in range(10):
    cube = cmds.polyCube()
    cubeTransform = cube[0] # cube is a list composed by cube transform name and polycube modificator
    cmds.setAttr("%s.translateX" % cube[0],15)
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting an expected result use this code:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

x = 0
y = 0
mc.polyCube( name = 'cube' )

for i in range(9):
    mc.polyCube( name = 'cube' )
    x += 15
    y += 3    
    mc.move( x, y, 0 )

mc.select( all = True )    
mc.scale( 5, 5, 5 )
```

[image]

Comment: Andy would you help me our privately on learning Maya Python ? kamwolk at gmail com

Comment: Sorry, Kam, I've got a busy schedule. The only thing I can do is to answer questions here. It takes only several minutes.